# How to turn text/html requests response into JSON format in python?

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I have a problem just like I mentioned in topic. Trying to get the name of all CVE's on website and their description. I want to iterate JSON response using for loop and send everything to DB. Code:

```
r = requests.get('https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvekey.cgi?keyword=microsoft')
r.headers['content-type']
```

After printing out the headers it shows me that the response is text/html and I cannot convert it into JSON. I was trying to do it like I usually do, following the documentation using `r.json()`. But after running code im getting error like this:

```
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I also tried `json.dumps()` , unfortunatelly didn't solve the problem. I was looking for the solution for hours and couldn't find anything that would help me convert this response into JSON. **Is this even possible with this website and this response? Can I do it differently? Is there any other good solution to achieve my goal?** If I wrote something not understendable, please correct me or ask me a question.

Thank you a lot in advance for any kind of a help. :-)

Comment: why do you think it is in JSON format?

Comment: Response for this API is not a json, instead ``Html`` u will need web-scrapping to get it done.

Comment: What do you mean by saying web-scrapping?

Answer (score 1):

Response for the API is not a JSON, instead its a HTML you can either use `Pandas` [read_html](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.read_html.html) or [Beautifulsoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to parse the details required, below is the example using pandas `read_html`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_html("https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvekey.cgi?keyword=Microsoft")

df[2].to_dict(orient='records')
```